# winbind authentication through apache slow

Tags: apache-2.4, samba, optimization, winbind

I have a linux machine setup to authenticate users using Active Directory with samba/winbind.

Apache is then setup to use that to authenticate the users. This is done using:

```
<IfModule mod_authnz_external.c>
    AddExternalAuth pwauth /usr/sbin/pwauth
    SetExternalAuthMethod pwauth pipe
</IfModule>
```

But page requests taking less than 1 second without auth now takes > 6 seconds. Looking at the log in `/var/log/samba/log.winbindd` does not show any errors but each page load seem to require a lot of of authentication requests. Basically there seem to be one authentication per resource loaded, for example for each css file.

In `/etc/samba/smb.conf` I have tried to play with some settings such as `winbind cache time = 300` and `winbind offline logon = yes`. I also tried to change the idmap backend from tdb to ad.

During the page load the cpu usage of winbindd gets very high, ~50-60% while no other process seem to go over 10-20%.

Have I misssed some config that could speed this up, or are there better approaches to this problem (like using something other than mod_authnz_external)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still didn't find how to improve the performance when using mod_authnz_external. However changing to another apache module mod_authnz_ldap got rid of the performance problem. The only downside then is that the ldap configuration is duplicated for the system and for apache.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar setup using Ubuntu 18.04 as client and Samba 4.7.8 as a server one authentication with *pwauth* takes around 200 ms, which is unacceptable for SVN operations because a simple repository listing uses quite a lot of requests.

Loading **authn_socache** as an authentication cache (example includes **authnz_external** and **authz_unixgroup**) with the following settings results in an improved performance:

```
<Location /svn>
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath /var/local/svn/
     SVNListParentPath on
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "private area"
     AuthBasicProvider socache external
     AuthExternal pwauth
     AuthExternalProvideCache on
     AuthnCacheProvideFor external
     AuthnCacheTimeout 300
     Require unix-group svngroup
</Location>
```

*AuthExternalProvideCache On* is important, otherwise **authnz_external** will not cache logins.